# Actualizar datos de la base de datos sqlite en assets

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Cuando realizo algun cambio en la informacion en la base de datos sqlite (cambiar algun nombre o algo), en la carpeta **assets/** reemplazo el archivo viejo **usuarios.db** por el archivo nuevo del mismo nombre, y antes de correr la app usando Android Studio tengo que desinstalar la app del dispositivo y volverla a instalar para que se reflejen los cambios.

**mi pregunta es**, que pasará cuando se realice la actualización desde Google Play... el sistema de Google desinstala la app vieja y la reemplaza por la nueva guardando los cambios o seguira mostrando la db vieja?

tengo entendido que para modificar tablas si es necesario cambiar el DATABASE_VERSION = 1, pero en este caso son solo datos, 
tambien leí que cambiara el nombre de la db con cada actualización, pero no estoy claro cual seria la mejor solucion

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tratar de cambiar un archivo de base de datos sqlite dentro de `/assets` , **No es posible, la razón es que el directorio `/assets` ( así como `/raw` ) son únicamente de lectura.**

Lo recomendable en este caso es realizar una copia del archivo de base de datos a otra ubicación por ejemplo la SD Card y ahí si podrás eliminarla, reemplazarla e incluso modificar su estructura y datos.

Con respecto a tu primera pregunta:

> que pasará cuando se realice la actualización desde Google Play... el
>   sistema de Google desinstala la app vieja y la reemplaza por la nueva
>   guardando los cambios o seguira mostrando la db vieja?

En este caso la actualización reemplazara todos los recursos, incluyendo tu base de datos.

Con respecto a tu segunda pregunta:

> tengo entendido que para modificar tablas si es necesario cambiar el
>   DATABASE_VERSION = 1, pero en este caso son solo datos, tambien leí
>   que cambiara el nombre de la db con cada actualización, pero no estoy
>   claro cual seria la mejor solucion

Esto solo aplica si tu creas la base de datos, obviamente no se puede crear dentro de `/assets` ya que es un directorio de solo lectura.